# Is there any way when click anywhere of iframe, it will redirect the website to a new website?

Tags: iframe, onclick

I used a iframe tag to show anther website. But I want people click wherever in the iframe, they can be redirect to another website as I shown in the iframe.

I tried to use onclick event, However, I found that it will not be support because of the security issue. Does anyone know how to do it instead of using onclick.

Comment: Just take a screenshot of the site, and have that as a link. The iframe is a serious waste of resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know it is a good trick or not but you can have a try with this technique

As a iframe source, set a page which is in your server and on that page create a "DIV" and under the "DIV" create one new iframe with another website url. Now set an onClick event on that "DIV" which is basically on your server page. Set an "opacity" through CSS class on that div.

```
<iframe src="file-in-your-server.html" ></iframe>
```

file-in-your-server.html

```
<div style=""><iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe></div>
```

Hope it works, I have not tried it yet.

Comment: Hey, I tried your idea, and I add a transparent div on the iframe tag, it works. Thanks for you trick!!